# Does debt-ceiling really need its own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Does [debt-ceiling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debt-ceiling) really need its own tag? Wouldn't any questions relevant to that just come under [debt](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debt) anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary purpose of tags is to connect experts with interesting questions to answer.

The question "should tag A be merged in tag B?" can be rephrased as "can a person be an expert on topic A but not on topic B?". If the answer to that is "no", then the tags should be merged.

In this case, I don't think anyone can be an expert on "debt ceilings" but *not* be an expert on "debt", so for the purpose of tags they are equivalent, and should thus be merged.

Since [debt-ceiling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debt-ceiling) has only three tags I would just manually retag them.